# Why when textbox is null and Len & Dir called causing Error: 13 Type Mismatch

Tags: vba

Every time the below code is ran Error Code: 13 Type Mismatch is reported.

```
If Not Len(Dir(Me.ImageURL)) = 0 Then
   Application.FollowHyperlink (Me.ImageURL)
End If
```

This only occurs when Me.ImageURL is equal to Null. Thus I attempted the following with no success.

```
If Not Len(Dir(Me.ImageURL)) = 0 And Not Nz(Me.ImageURL, "") = "" Then
    Application.FollowHyperlink (Me.ImageURL)
End If
```

Comment: What is `Me` in your code context? A user form? A sheet? Please,  try preliminary checking if the text box contains any text: `If Me.ImageURL.Text <> "" Then` followed by your code and ending with `End If`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget the If statements. Just use the `Nz` function.

```
Application.FollowHyperlink Nz(Me.ImageURL, "")
```

Your particular problem, if you want to know, is `Dir(Me.ImageURL)`. I'm guessing `Dir` can't handle a Null value.